# How to upgrade Infragistics control to work in IE11?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I have ASP.NET applications with versions 6.2 and 7.1.  With IE11 I have
   problems.

The most used controls are:  UltraWebGrid,  UltraWebTab, 
   WebDateChooser,  UltraWebNavigator,  WebCombo,  Shared

Can I automatically migrate these controls to new version, or I have to
   re-program?

What version would I need to use?

And how to upgrade these controls to be support the IE version 11?

Comment: Why not just upgrade to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the controls you are using were retired and last included in NetAdvantage 2011 Volume 1 and you can find more details in [NetAdvantage for ASP.NET Product Changes in 2011 Volume 2](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/taz_abdeali/archive/2011/11/17/asp-net-product-changes-in-2011-volume-2.aspx).  If you want to upgrade without rewriting 2011 Volume 1 is the last volume you could use though this still had its last service release before the release of IE11 so it wasn't tested or supported with IE11.

If you wish to see if upgrading to 2011 Volume 1 would work for you, you can download a trial from the [archived downloads page](http://www.infragistics.com/products/downloads/archived).

If you find that 2011 Volume 1 will not work, then you can look at the latest volume of Infragistics [ASP.NET controls](http://www.infragistics.com/products/aspnet) or [jQuery controls](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery) to see if they will meet your needs.